# First value (Oracle) equivalent in Hive

Tags: sql, oracle, hive, analytic-functions

I want to create hive query for the following.

```
insert into  tempTableName  
select distinct col_a
        ,  first_value(col_b)  
            over (partition by col_a 
            order by nvl(col_c,0) desc, length(col_b) asc, col_b asc) 
from tableA
```

As hive does not support first value.I want to know what could be the equivalent in simple query for first_value function.
Any suggestions ??

Comment: As there is growing interest in using Hive SQL through the SQL engine of [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html), it's worth noting that Spark does support `first_value()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly familiar with the oracle semantics here, but isn't this just a group by and arg-min? Structs in hive compare in the order of their fields, so you can do something like this:

```
select col_a,
min(
  named_struct(
    'col_c', -coalesce(col_c, 0),
    'len' , length(col_b),
    'col_b', col_b
  )
).col_b
from tableA
group by col_a
```

Answer (score 1):

`HIVE 0.11` does support `FIRST_VALUE`.

But as per [HIVE JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4662), there's an open issue that you cannot have more than one `ORDER BY` column in `first_value`. You haven't reported what error you are getting, but if it's `FAILED: SemanticException Range based Window Frame can have only 1 Sort Key`, then you have to modify the `ORDER BY` columns.

***Edit:*** If you are not on `HIVE 0.11`, then I would suggest installing a `UDF` for `FIRST_VALUE`. I guess that would be the straightforward way to do this. You might want to take a look at [these UDFS](https://github.com/paulmw/hive-udf).

Comment: I am not using 0.11. How do I write this in a simple query without any functions

Comment: edited my answer. You could install an `UDF` and work with that